# How to identify the variable of thread-last?

Tags: clojure

Consider the following code:

```
(defn delete-last-line [list]
  (take (- (count list) 1) list)
  )

(->>
(create-list)
(delete-last-line))
```

Now i would like to replace delete-last-line by an anonymous function in thread-last. Something like the following, but this will not work. The problem is the i need to somehow have an identifier of the variable.

```
 (take (- (count %) 1))
```

Comment: Not what you are asking, but there is `butlast`

Comment: Also consider [as->](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/as-%3E).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an extra pair of parens around your anonymous function so you're calling it; that way `->>` threads into the *invocation* of the function, not its *definition*.

```
(->>
  (create-list)
  (#(take (- (count %) 1) %)))
```

I don't know what you mean by "somehow have an identifier of the variable", but if you want to give it a name instead of using `%`, you can always do that:

```
(println
  (->>
    (create-list)
    ((fn [lst] (take (- (count lst) 1) lst)))))
```